# Get count of relations from eloquent collection

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have `Call` model. Each call has `Theme`. How i did this:

```
class Call extends Model
{
    // some code here

    public function theme()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Theme::class, 'id', 'theme_id')->withTrashed();
    }

    // some code there
}
```

This works great. What i want to do is get count of each themes used in all calls.

There is 200 calls for example. 100 of them has `theme_id=3`, 50 of them has `6`, and last 50 has `8`. I want to get result like:

```
{
  {theme_id:3, themes_count=100},
  {theme_id:6, themes_count=50},
  {theme_id:8, themes_count=50},
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\DB::select("select theme_id, count(*) themes_count from calls group by theme_id");
```

Or using QueryBuilder:

```
Call::selectRaw("count(*) themes_count,  theme_id")
    ->groupBy("theme_id")
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! Can i do it using `Eloquent` query builder?

Answer (score 1):

In eloquent query builder:

```
$collection = Theme::groupBy('theme_id')
->selectRaw('theme_id, count(*) as themes_count')
->get();
```